# Table is getting too big

Tags: html, css

```
<table border="1" style="width:200px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50px;overflow:hidden;">Who</td>
    <td style="width:50px;overflow:hidden;">Time</td>
    <td style="width:100px;overflow:hidden;">What</td>
  </tr>
<?php 
while($wr = mysqli_fetch_array($read)) {
    echo' <tr>
    <td>'.$wr['Who'].'</td>
    <td>'.$wr['Time'].'</td>
    <td>'.$wr['What'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

?>

$wr['What'] is pulling big data from database and my table is going over 200px. How can I fix it ?

Comment: +1 for still using tables for layout!

Comment: He's not using tables for layout.  He's using table for a neat representation of tabular data... Appropriate, no?

Comment: @MattMurrell You're right! `<table>` is so versatile that way. Excellent for displaying data and simply first-class when it comes to layout :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `table-layout:fixed` and it should force it...

```
style="width:200px;table-layout:fixed"
```

[Here's a fiddle with appropriate css.](http://jsfiddle.net/ChxV2/1)

Comment: With this solution the contents of the table might "spill outside" the bounds of the table. If you want to hide the "spill over" you can add "overflow: hidden" to the `td` elements within the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `max-width` property in CSS on your td to set the maximum width of whatever you want

```
style='max-width:100px'
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Chrome. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/nkMKt/   `table-layout:fixed` does.

Comment: Yes I tried that one it didn`t work. Thank you for the help tho.